# Excel: multiple word replacement with a lookup matrix

Tags: excel, replace, match

I have a list with words ("big list"). I want to replace certain words from that list with other pre-defined words ("replace with"). I'm using "checklist" to tell the formula which words to replace. This works with ONE word per replacement group.

However I need to use multiple replacement words as depicted in the bottom example. I thought I might be able to use the checklist matrix match number somehow, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

[image]

**EDIT:** I expanded the answer below to catch empty cells - These don't work with the match: `=IF(ISBLANK(A17),"EMPTY",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A17,B$17:B$20,0)),A17,INDEX(C$17:C$20,MATCH(A17,B$17:B$20,0))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right, you just need to use INDEX to get the replacement string from column C corresponding to the number you got from MATCH:-

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A17,B$17:B$20,0)),A17,INDEX(C$17:C$20,MATCH(A17,B$17:B$20,0)))
```

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$17:C$20,MATCH(A17,B$17:B$20,0)),A17)
```

[image]